# Convert cropped images to gif with imagemagick : size conflict

Tags: imagemagick, crop, gif

I want to create an animated gif, I thus use this command :

> convert  -delay 50 --loop 0 cropped*.png  animated.gif

where the cropped*.png are images that have been previously cropped from 1920x1080 size images with the command :

> convert -crop 1105x441+92+168 source-1.png cropped-1.png

The command `display -verbose` gives this result :

> PNG 1105x441 1920x1080+92+168

The problem is that the resulting gif, when played with eog or in any presentation software (libreimppress, etc) have the size   1920x1080 and not 1105x441. And I can't figure out why.

Comment: I found a solution, if I add the +repage command, it solves the problem :

 ``convert -crop 1105x441+92+168 +repage source-1.png cropped-1.png``